# Facing issue related to 'Microsoft.NETCore.App was not found while building the Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have recently upgraded my package from .net 3.1 to .net 6.0 . I am getting error in build pipeline  : The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64) was not found.

- The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.5 at [C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:

- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

Please let me know how to fix this in Azure pipeline .

Comment: i think you've updated to net5 not net6. so you probably want to update you're app to target net6. by default only LTS version of dotnet are installed on agent.

Comment: Project has been updated to .net 6 . I changed in the Project properties .

Comment: The link you pasted is for net5 tho.

Comment: I am getting this error in the pipeline after upgrading the packages .

Answer (score 1):

If you're having problems with your pipeline tasks, make sure for `YAML` your agent is set to **`Windows 2022`**.

Set **SDK** to `6.0.102` if your pipeline uses GUI.

[image]

**YAML Code for setting up the agent**:

```
pool:  
vmImage: 'windows-2022'

variables:  
solution: '**/*.sln'  
buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'  
buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:  
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

-   task: PowerShell@2  
    inputs:  
    targetType: 'inline'  
    script: |  
    $newBuildNumber = echo ($(PowerShell_Version_Build_Number)+$(PowerShell_Version_Build_Number))  
    ((Get-Content -path Directory.Build.props -Raw) -replace 'BUILD_NUMBER', $newBuildNumber) | Set-Content -Path Directory.Build.props  
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.Your_Local_Directory_Path)'
    
-   task: PowerShell@2  
    inputs:  
    targetType: 'inline'  
    script: Get-Content -path Directory.Build.props -Raw  
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.Your_Local_Directory_Path)'
    
-   task: NuGetCommand@2  
    inputs:  
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    
-   task: VSBuild@1  
    inputs:  
    solution: '$(solution)'  
    msbuildArgs: '[your_build_args]'  
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'  
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    
-   task: VSTest@2  
    inputs:  
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'  
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    
-   task: CopyFiles@2  
    displayName: 'Copying files'  
    condition: and(succeeded(), true)  
    inputs:  
    Contents: '[Project path]/bin/**'  
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/[Your_Project_path]'
```